# bash script to edit xml file

Tags: xml, bash, editing

I want to edit the config file of a program that is an XML:

```
<software>
   <settings>
       ...
       <setting name="local directory" type="string">/home/username/</setting>
       ...
   </settings>
</software>
```

What is the easiest way to do this from a bash script?

Thanks

Comment: What edit do you want to make?

Comment: the setting called local directory, its value

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do, you may want to use some XML-specific tooling (to handle character encodings, to maintain XML well-formedness etc.). You can use the normal line-oriented tools, but unless you're careful (or doing something trivial) you can easily create non-compliant XML.

I use the [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) command line set. It's a set of command line utilities for specifically parsing/manipulating XML.

Comment: +1 to above comment for use of the word dandy.
+1 to post for great reference.

Comment: But what about something that's installed by default?

Comment: @TomášZato, ...then you end up using Python (which has several XML modules built in).

Answer (score 20):

Using xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet val -e file.xml
xmlstarlet ed -u "//settings/setting/@name" -v 'local directory2' file.xml
xmlstarlet ed -u "//settings[1]/setting/@name" -v 'local directory2' file.xml

# edit file inplace
xmlstarlet ed -L -u "//settings/setting/@name" -v 'local directory2' file.xml
```

Comment: I don't have -L option to edit in place, what edition of xmlstartlet and unix are you using?

Comment: Ah, brilliant - the -L option was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score -4):

Most people would probably use sed to do line editing from a bash script. If you 
actually care about parsing the XML, then use something like Perl which has a ready XML parser.

Comment: This could be a way of solving the problem. But in that case please try to add some sample codes for that. Don't give vague sentences.

Answer (score -4):

An ugly/unsafe but sometimes the easiest is to call sed/perl/awk from bash