# How do I select and edit an xml node with xmlstartlet?

Tags: xml, bash, command-line-interface

Here I'm selecting the node:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/configuration/property[name='http.agent.name']"/value conf/nutch-default.xml 
<value/>
```

This doesn't edit it:

```
$ xmlstarlet edit  "/configuration/property[name='http.agent.name']"/value -v 'test' conf/nutch-default.xml 
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/configuration/property[name='http.agent.name']/value"
```

What would be an xmlstartlet command that does change the change? AFAIK -x is not supported in xmlstartlet yet.

I'm working on [conf/nutch-default.xml](http://www.webcitation.org/query?url=http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/nutch/branches/branch-1.3/conf/nutch-default.xml?view=markup&date=2011-04-08)

```
$ xmlstarlet ed --help
XMLStarlet Toolkit: Edit XML document(s)
Usage: xml ed <global-options> {<action>} [ <xml-file-or-uri> ... ]
where
  <global-options>  - global options for editing
  <xml-file-or-uri> - input XML document file name/uri (stdin otherwise)

<global-options> are:
  -P (or --pf)        - preserve original formatting
  -S (or --ps)        - preserve non-significant spaces
  -O (or --omit-decl) - omit XML declaration (<?xml ...?>)
  -N <name>=<value>   - predefine namespaces (name without 'xmlns:')
                        ex: xsql=urn:oracle-xsql
                        Multiple -N options are allowed.
                        -N options must be last global options.
  --help or -h        - display help

where <action>
  -d or --delete <xpath>
  -i or --insert <xpath> -t (--type) elem|text|attr -n <name> -v (--value) <value>
  -a or --append <xpath> -t (--type) elem|text|attr -n <name> -v (--value) <value>
  -s or --subnode <xpath> -t (--type) elem|text|attr -n <name> -v (--value) <value>
  -m or --move <xpath1> <xpath2>
  -r or --rename <xpath1> -v <new-name>
  -u or --update <xpath> -v (--value) <value>
             -x (--expr) <xpath> (-x is not implemented yet)

XMLStarlet is a command line toolkit to query/edit/check/transform
XML documents (for more information see http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)

$ xmlstarlet --version
1.0.1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may read the entire contents of nutch-default.xml to a variable, edit the contents of that variable with xmlstarlet and then write the result back to nutch-default.xml again.

Another way would be to use open file handles as described in [Redirect output from sed 's/c/d/' myFile to myFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585438/redirect-output-from-sed-s-c-d-myfile-to-myfile) .

```
xmlstarlet --version  # 1.0.6
xmlstarlet ed --help | less -Ip 'inplace'

# 1.
# in-place version using xmlstarlet only
curl -L -s -o nutch-default.xml 'http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/nutch/branches/branch-1.3/conf/nutch-default.xml?view=co&revision=1079746&content-type=text%2Fplain'
xmlstarlet edit -L -u "/configuration/property[name='http.agent.name']"/value -v 'test' nutch-default.xml
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/configuration/property[name='http.agent.name']"/value nutch-default.xml 


# 2.
# variable version
curl -L -s -o nutch-default.xml 'http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/nutch/branches/branch-1.3/conf/nutch-default.xml?view=co&revision=1079746&content-type=text%2Fplain'
xmlstr="$(< nutch-default.xml)"   # save file contents to variable

printf '%s\n' "$xmlstr" |
xmlstarlet edit -u "/configuration/property[name='http.agent.name']"/value -v 'test' > nutch-default.xml

xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/configuration/property[name='http.agent.name']"/value nutch-default.xml 


# 3.
# file handle version
# cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585438/redirect-output-from-sed-s-c-d-myfile-to-myfile
curl -L -s -o nutch-default.xml 'http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/nutch/branches/branch-1.3/conf/nutch-default.xml?view=co&revision=1079746&content-type=text%2Fplain'
exec 3<nutch-default.xml
rm nutch-default.xml   # prevent open file from being truncated
xmlstarlet edit -u "/configuration/property[name='http.agent.name']"/value -v 'test' <&3 >nutch-default.xml
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/configuration/property[name='http.agent.name']"/value nutch-default.xml
```

Comment: thank you! I've $ sudo port upgrade xmlstarlet and now I managed to use -L, which lived to expectations.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation is very very poor. I stumbled across Stackoverflow for more than a day and after reading through many answers on stack overflow I finally derived the solution for "edit file inplace option" for the value of an element with namespaces defined. Given an XML as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <cassandra xmlns="http://venus.com/ns/mibs/VENUS-MODE/1.0">
    <clusterName>test-cluster</clusterName>
    <cassandraUsername>simba</cassandraUsername>
    <cassandraPassword>U2FsdGVkX1/Zc4NAsF59coYZLaCgddJ9b91s016HUbs=</cassandraPassword>
    <cassandraService>Local</cassandraService>
  </cassandra>
  <monit xmlns="http://venus.com/ns/mibs/VENUS-MODE/1.0">
    <cpuUsageThreshold>70</cpuUsageThreshold>
    <cpuUsageThresholdClear>60</cpuUsageThresholdClear>
    <memoryUsageThreshold>70</memoryUsageThreshold>
    <memoryUsageThresholdClear>60</memoryUsageThresholdClear>
  </monit>
</config>
```

The xmlstarlet command to modify /config/cassandra/clusterName element value would be:

> xmlstarlet ed -L -N x="http://venus.com/ns/mibs/VENUS-MODE/1.0" -u
>   "//config/x:cassandra/x:cassandraPassword" -v "test123" Myfile.xml

Remember ed & -L option must precede -N (namespace) option. Hope this helps somebody looking for edit file inplace option with namespace issues.

Comment:  Absolutely legendary. Thank you - the man pages do not explain any of the switches and especially there are no examples on how to deal with tags that are nested in a tag with a specific namespace.

Answer (score 2):

My version of `xmlstarlet` needs an `action` option to the `edit` command. If you want to update the node with a new value you have to specify `-u`, e.g.:

```
xmlstarlet edit -u "/configuration/property[name='http.agent.name']"/value -v 'test' conf/nutch-default.xml
```

Comment: @bmk: you are right! But that now prints to stdout, -L should modify the file but apparently not in my edition. How else can i? redirecting output with > empties the file only

Comment: @simpatico: My version of `xmlstarlet` doesn't seem to have any `-L` option. Can you give me the full command line? Then I will update my answer.

Comment: @bmk: neither my version, I'm referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554143/bash-script-to-edit-xml-file . How else can we modify the file with the update?

Comment: @simpatico: I think we have to redirect the command's output to a new temporary file and move it over the original file afterwards (`xmlstarlet edit -u "/configuration/property[name='http.agent.name']"/value -v 'test' conf/nutch-default.xml > conf/nutch-default.xml.tmp; mv conf/nutch-default.xml.tmp conf/nutch-default.xml`).

Comment: @bmk: I think sed would then be easier to use

Comment: I think that strongly depends on what you actually want to do and the formatting and the complexity of the XML file. I know a lot of XML files that I cannot imagine to edit via sed.