# Add text to specific line linux script

Tags: linux, sed, scripting

I need to create a script that will add text after a specific line in a file (XML). Here is what I have so far:

```
echo
echo "This script will blah blah blah"
echo
read -p "Press Enter to continue..."
clear

var1=`grep -n "<string>" <file> | awk -F ":" '{print $1}'` //var1 = line number

function EnterID()
{
echo -n "Enter ID: "
read ID
var2="text to be added"
sed "$((var1+1))i$var2" <file> > <file> //add text to file, overwrite file
#var1="$((var1+1))" //increment line number???
echo
echo "ID successfully added to file"
echo
EnterNewID
}

EnterNewID()
{
read -p "Press Enter to continue..."
clear
echo -n "Would you like to add another ID? (y)es or (n)o: "
read answer
clear

if [ $answer = "y" ]; then
    EnterID
else
    exit
fi
}

EnterID
```

The script works the first time around. However, if the users attempts to add an additional ID the first ID is overwritten. I should also state I am not a programmer (more of a network guy). I have a little experience scripting but that's all.

Additional Information:

Original:

```
<SubscriberXML>
  <Subscribers> 
    <Subscriber address="0.0.0.0" id="1" />
    <Subscriber address="0.0.0.0" id="2" />
    <Subscriber address="0.0.0.0" id="3" />
    <Subscriber address="0.0.0.0" id="4" />
    <Subscriber address="0.0.0.0" id="5" />
  </Subscribers>
</SubscriberXML>
```

After initial use:

```
<SubscriberXML>
  <Subscribers> 
    <Subscriber address="0.0.0.0" id="X" /> // newly added ID
    <Subscriber address="0.0.0.0" id="1" />
    <Subscriber address="0.0.0.0" id="2" />
    <Subscriber address="0.0.0.0" id="3" />
    <Subscriber address="0.0.0.0" id="4" />
    <Subscriber address="0.0.0.0" id="5" />
  </Subscribers>
</SubscriberXML>
```

After second use:

```
<SubscriberXML>
  <Subscribers> 
    <Subscriber address="0.0.0.0" id="Y" /> // newly added ID
    <Subscriber address="0.0.0.0" id="1" />
    <Subscriber address="0.0.0.0" id="2" />
    <Subscriber address="0.0.0.0" id="3" />
    <Subscriber address="0.0.0.0" id="4" />
    <Subscriber address="0.0.0.0" id="5" />
  </Subscribers>
</SubscriberXML>
```

Want:

```
<SubscriberXML>
  <Subscribers> 
    <Subscriber address="0.0.0.0" id="Y" />
    <Subscriber address="0.0.0.0" id="X" />
    <Subscriber address="0.0.0.0" id="1" />
    <Subscriber address="0.0.0.0" id="2" />
    <Subscriber address="0.0.0.0" id="3" />
    <Subscriber address="0.0.0.0" id="4" />
    <Subscriber address="0.0.0.0" id="5" />
  </Subscribers>
</SubscriberXML>
```

Comment: Hi, could you provide an example of the file you want to overwrite, and the expected result(s)? It would help.

Comment: I would suggest you to use some xml processing tool instead of combinator of sed and awk here. Have you seen xmlstarlet tool?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591414

Comment: @marbu this is not an option running Tiny Core linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
any_command file > file
```

The shell will process the redirection **first**, and  the file  will be truncated **before** the shell launches the command. You're now passing an empty file  to the command.

There are a couple of techniques:

1. use a temp file and overwrite the original file if the command completed successfully

   ```
   temp=$(mktemp)
   any_command file > "$temp" && mv "$temp" file
   ```
2. install the `moreutils` package and use the `sponge` command

   ```
   any_command file | sponge file
   ```

Comment: You're right when I tried doing file > file I was left with a blank file. However, during testing I used file > testfile which did yield the correct output after first use. Anyways, my problem still exists.

Comment: If you never write "testfile" back to "file", the sed command is never going to see the updated file.

Comment: thanks glenn. I got it working using command file > "$temp" && mv "$temp" file. Like you stated it simply wasn't using the updated file.

Answer (score 0):

The program and the problem would be much simpler if you just collected all the additions, then did a single replacement.

```
nl='
'
replace="i\\$nl"
while read -p "What should be added? (Empty input to finish) " entry; do
    if [ "$entry" = "" ]; then
        break
    fi
    replace="$replace$nl$entry"
done
sed -i "/<string>/$replace" file
```